# Writing csv with python

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a python script in which I generate a csv from numbers I computed.

The rows I write are:

```
writeRow = [str(t), len(c) , {k for k in c.keys()}, {k for k in c.values()}]
```

I have two problems:

1. `t` is a number that can begin by 0. But in that case, the 0 is deleted.
   I tried without `str()` but it doesn't change...
2. the sets are printed as sets in the cells. However, I want to write these numbers separated by commas in the same cell and without the `{}` How can I do that?

**edit**

I am using the csv module;  In the code, I create lists for each row to write and then write them with csv.writerow

I'm gonna post more code:

```
from csv import reader, writer
with open(fileName1) as inp, open(fileName2,'w') as o:
```

I then define the reader, writer, and the variables t,c

```
writeRow = [str(t), len(c) , {k for k in c.keys()}, {k for k in c.values()}]
```

Then I write the result in the output file

**Edit** 
form of t and what a row should look like

t = 023
t = 123
t is an int

The line in the end should look like:

```
cell1  cell2         cell3       cell4 
123    2     string1,string2    num1,num2
```

string1 and str2 are the dict keys; num1,num2 the corresponding values

Comment: Why not just use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: Actually this is what I do. In the code, I create lists for each row to write and then write them with csv.writerow

Comment: Please post a line as you want it to be rendered. Do you have to same amount of columns (`len(c)`) for each row? CSV does not fit very well otherwise.

Comment: I think you'd be wise to show more code. I'm not sure what your point 1 means. `t` can begin with zero?

Comment: What is `type(t)`? Is it a `str` that represents a number? Is `076` supposed to be octal? `076 == 62`.

Comment: str representing a number

Comment: Please post an example for `t` and `c` and how the line should look like.

Comment: Look at the latest edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string formatting for the padding with 0s, and join for the sets:

```
writeRow = ['{:0>3}'.format(t), len(c) , ','.join(c.keys()), ','.join(c.values())]
```

note that you should not enter your value for `t` with a leading `0`:

```
>>>t = 023
>>>t
19
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you can take advantage of the `join()` method (assuming keys and values are strings):

```
",".join(c.keys()) + "," + ",".join(c.values())
```

This will take care of commas. However, this will break very easily for any non-trivial data, so consider using [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module instead, which would take care of escaping dangerous characters.

Comment: This returns in each cell d,i,c,t,_,k,e,y,s,(key_names)

Answer (score 1):

What about using format strings?

```
'%s,%i'%(t,c)
```

might do what you want. You could also use '%03i' or something similar to produce some padding zeros before your number. Or, I might misunderstand your question. Try posting a more complete (runnable) example.

Comment: I think my question was not clear (I edited it with an example)